# Continuous action of a connected topological group on a discrete space is trivial

Tags: general-topology, group-actions, topological-groups

I know that this is a very easy exercise from Lee's SM book, but I don't know how to start. here is the question:

> **Q:** Suppose a connected topological group $G$ acts continuously on a discrete
>   space $K$. Show that the action is trivial.

If $g\in G$ s.t. $m(g,k)=gk\neq k$ then one can look at $m^{-1}(gk)$. How to proceed from here? please don't answer directly and a hint suffices.

Comment: What do you know about the orbits of the action?

Comment: Just its definition!

Comment: What can you deduce from the hypotheses, that the action is continuous and $G$ connected?

Comment: $G\times K$ is connected.

Comment: That only if $K$ consists of at most one point. I meant "What can you deduce about the orbits …".

Comment: $G$ is connected so $G.p$ is connected.

Comment: Right. Now, what are the connected subsets of a discrete space?

Comment: points. so $G.p={p}$. Right?

Comment: Pedantically, also the empty set. Yes, it follows that the orbits are singletons. And you're done.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I have another problem. after many years of topology course, I can't remember quickly which map (discrete domain or discrete image) is continuous and why!! this happened for me 3 times and each time I referred to a topology book. Is there a easy way to remember?

Comment: Since continuity is defined in terms of preimages of open/closed sets, the more open/closed sets in the domain, and/or the fewer in the codomain, the easier it is for a map to be continuous. Maybe "**d**omain **d**iscrete; **t**arget **t**rivial" works as a pons asinorum.

Comment: Great!  D-D "domain discrete". Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If $m: G \times K \to K$ is the action, $O(k):=\{m(g,k): g \in G\} \subseteq K$, the orbit of $k$, is connected as the continuous image of $G \times \{k\} \simeq G$, and so must be a singleton, as the only connected non-empty subsets of a discrete space are singletons. Ergo $m(g,k)=k = m(1,k)$ for any $g,k$.